# Optimizing performance of transaction search query in ASP.NET Core using Entity Framework with multiple related tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a transaction history table on which I need to implement a search.
I kind of did this, but I'm not satisfied with what I got and I want to improve the performance as much as possible.

The query looks like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchField))
{
                var externalAddresses = await 
         _context.ExternalAddresses.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchField)).Select(x => x.Address).ToListAsync();

                transactions = transactions
                    .Include(x => x.SenderUserInfo)
                    .Include(x => x.ReceiverUserInfo)
                    .Include(x => x.FiatTransactions)
                    .Where(x =>
                        x.CurrencyInName.Contains(searchField) ||
                        x.CurrencyInSymbol.Contains(searchField) ||
                        x.CurrencyOutName.Contains(searchField) ||
                        x.CurrencyOutSymbol.Contains(searchField) ||
                        x.SenderUserInfo.UserTag.Contains(searchField) ||
                        x.ReceiverUserInfo.UserTag.Contains(searchField) ||
                        x.FiatTransactions
                            .Where(x => x.SenderName.Contains(searchField) ||
                                        x.BeneficiaryName.Contains(searchField))
                            .Any() ||
                        (externalAddresses.Any(y => y == x.Country) || externalAddresses.Any(y => y == x.City))
                    )
                    .AsSplitQuery();
}
```

External addresses represents the users saved addresses e.g: Country = Canada, City = Vancouver, Name = Home / Country = USA, City = Chicago, Name = Holiday - it does not have a relation with transaction table

Transaction table has:
1:1 rel with userInfo in which i store data about the users
1:M rel with FiatTransaction in which i store data about the fiat transaction that im receiving from the API i'm using. (it generate 2 transactions one for the sender and one for the receiver)

I tried to use indexes for the most used properties from each table, but it didn't improve the performance too much

Comment: Don't use such a query to begin with. It can't be optimized because it can't use any indexes. At the very least you need to use the Full Text Search capabilities of your database to create a specialized FTS index and query it. Most databases have FTS indexes in one form or another. SQL Server for example [has a Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) feature. You can use the `FREETEXT` function through `EF.Functions.FreeText`

Comment: On the other hand, `StartsWith` translates to `LIKE 'whatever%'` which can take advantage of indexes. It's still not the most efficient query though